# Create a Frame image from single image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, arkit

I want to make a frame image from single image. Below is the code I'm using

```
func createFrameFromImage(image:UIImage , size :CGSize) -> UIImage
    {
 let imageSize = CGSize.init(width: size.width , height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize)
        let width = imageSize.width
        let height = imageSize.height
        var letTop = image
        let rightTop = rotateImageByAngles(image: &letTop, angles: .pi/2) // correct
        let rightBottom = rotateImageByAngles(image: &letTop, angles: -.pi) // correct
        let leftBottom = rotateImageByAngles(image: &letTop, angles: -.pi/2) // correct
        letTop.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width/2, height: height/2))
        rightTop.draw(in: CGRect(x: (width/2) , y: 0, width: width/2, height: height/2))
        leftBottom.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: height/2, width: width/2, height: height/2))
        rightBottom.draw(in: CGRect(x: (width/2) , y: (height/2), width: width/2, height: height/2))
        guard let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return rightTop }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return finalImage
    }
```

Above function takes one piece of image and create four different images by rotating a single at specific angle and merge them to make a frame image. Issue I'm facing is maintaining image ratio. for ex: if create final image of size 320 * 120 it squeezes image horizontally.Attaching screen shot of output. I want to show this new generated image on wall using ARkit.

**Final frame image**

[image: Final frame image]

**Given Image**

[image: Given Image]

```
 // Adding Frame
    // 1 inch = 72 points
    //converting size inch to points to create frame image
    let frameWidth = (size.width + 1)
    let frameHeight = (size.height + 1)
    let imgFrameUnit = UIImage(named: "img.png")!
    let imgFrame = Singleton.shared.createFrameFromImage(image: imgFrameUnit, size: CGSize(width: frameWidth , height: frameHeight))

    let frame = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: ((frameWidth * 2.54) / 100), height: ((frameHeight * 2.54) / 100))) // in meters
    frame.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = imgFrame
    frame.name = "frame"
    nodeWeCanChange?.addChildNode(frame)
```

Any Help would be really Appreciated?

Comment: Wouldn't it be far simpler to have an SCNNode which is actually a picture frame, and then scale it based on the image?

Comment: @BlackMirrorz - i don't have frame image. i want to create a frame from a single available image.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, Do u want create outer box for Single image?

Comment: @McDonal_11 - sorry  i don't understand what outer box is ? but simple just want to frame a picture on a wall and that frame is created dynamically by merging images

Comment: Given Image, R u getting from API or In Local Image Assets ??

Comment: @McDonal_11 - local image asset it is

Comment: Will do some Trick: Rotate the same image with four respective angle and save as four images in local assets. View Hierarchy: 1. View 2. Four ImageView [Equal widths and height inside that View], 3. ImageView [which Picture has been shown with FRAME, give constraints {15,15,15,15}]

Comment: @McDonal_11 - I'm doing same. posted . my code also and some sizes it works perfectly like 24 * 13 inches 30 * 16 inches but when i decrease size to 12 * 6 . it does not maintain ratio. attached output image also

Comment: I think u r rotating ur image through coding. Am I right?

Comment: @McDonal_11 - yes

Comment: for now i kept it locally for testing. but will get frames images from api

Comment: You want that Outer Frame according to that Chose Image Size? It may be, 320*240, 100*40, right ??

Comment: @McDonal_11 - yes